# Sample size estimation for linear regression with repeated measurements

Tags: regression, hypothesis-testing, sample-size, statistical-power

i'm in a bit of a pickle.

I have a quantity y that I want to estimate from a measurement x, via linear regression.

Per data point, i can repeat n-times the measurement of x, e.g. to get a better estimate, and average out the noise.

Question is, assuming that sampling x is costly, how do I estimate the best n? in other words, how do I make a sample size estimation of the repeatition needed *per data point* to have a good estimate of the regression?

Comment: If you have substantial errors in measuring `x`, did you take that into account in developing your linear regression model? Standard linear regression assumes no error in `x`, although there are [errors-in-variables models](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Errors-in-variables_models) that can handle errors in `x`. Also, please say something about the cost of your making an error in your estimate of `y`, as that will inform how much to invest in measuring `x`.

Comment: What you mean linear regression does not assume errors? There is always noise in every real life measurements

Comment: You are correct that there is always noise in real life, but an assumption underlying standard linear regression modeling is that the predictor values `x` are known exactly. That could be taken to mean that the errors in `x` are much smaller than corresponding errors in predicting outcome values `y`. In practice, the problem with potential errors in `x` is often simply ignored, rather than evaluating with an errors-in-variables model. Use your understanding of the subject matter to determine if that's a problem in your situation.

Comment: I know that if I average out about n=10 measurements of the same object I get a pretty good estimate of y. But I can’t take 10 measurements of the same data points, it’s too expensive. I have to have the least amount, that can give me a reasonable good correlation. Sort of a sample size estimation, but different

Comment: It sounds like there is a tradeoff here between the number of individuals n and measurement occasions t, where each measurement costs c dollars and you have some budget such that c*n*t <= B. But it is not clear what you want to maximize/minimize subject to that constraint. Is it estimating some population parameter? Could you write down the regression that you want to estimate (like $y_i =  x_i + \varepsilon_{it}$). Is the measurement error correlated over time for the same person? Is it correlated across people? Or is it just random noise in each period? That is the key to this problem.

Comment: Also, it is can be less costly to get repeated measures on the same person than an equivalent number of measurements for the same people, so that measuring 2 people twice is less expensive than 1 measurement for 4 people. If that's the case, you should edit your question with those details.

Answer (score 0):

Two possibilities here. One is that you have a pre-defined regression model that you want to put into practice by estimating `y` values from expensive measurements of the associated `x` value. The second is that you are now developing a regression model for the first time.

*Applying a pre-defined regression model*

For the first scenario, the big question is how large an error you are willing to accept in your estimate of `y`. There presumably is some cost in not knowing `y` exactly. You seem already to have pilot data that you can use to estimate the precision in estimates of `y` as a function of the number of measurements done on `x`.

Each extra measurement of `x` gives you less error in predicting `y` and a correspondingly lower cost of not knowing `y`. That lower cost is the "marginal benefit" of doing an extra measurement of `x`. Elementary economics suggests that you should choose a number of measurements of `x` such that the cost of the last measurement equals its marginal benefit.

*Developing a new regression model*

In general, you will get better estimates of the slope of the regression if your `x` values cover a wide range over which linearity with outcome `y` holds. That would be more important than having multiple replicates at individual values. From the Wikipedia page on [simple linear regression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_linear_regression#Normality_assumption)

> Under the first assumption above, that of the normality of the error terms, the estimator of the slope coefficient will itself be normally distributed with mean $\beta$ and variance $\sigma^2 / \sum (x_i - \bar x)^2$, where $\sigma^2$ is the variance of the error terms.

So wide variance in `x` values gives the most precise estimate of a regression coefficient, provided that the modeling assumptions hold. If you have some choice in setting the `x` values, choose them widely.

Note that you might need a large number of measurements of `x` to get a reliable value of `y` *either* because of errors in measuring `x` *or* because there is a large residual error in `y` even if `x` is known perfectly. The latter is the usual assumption in standard linear regression models. Think about that first. It's quite possible that the main problem is in variability of `y` even if `x` is known perfectly. Then you have a standard power/sample size calculation for linear regression to match against your cost constraints for measuring `x` values.

If both `x` and `y` have appreciable errors, then you might need to consider an [errors-in-variables model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Errors-in-variables_models). If you have estimates of the variance in measuring `x` and the variance in `y` when `x` is known perfectly, then you could do a [Deming regression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deming_regression) that accounts for the relative variances in `x` and `y`. But even in that scenario, if cost is limiting, it's more important to cover a wide range of `x` values than to have multiple measurements at individual `x` values.

Comment: I can’t increase the number of Xs I get, that leaves me with the first case. Which seems to be close to what I want. Just to be clear, I have y correlated to x, I know that they are correlated. But what I want to check is, given that the instrument to measure x is expensive and prone to noise, how many times should I measure each point x, so that when I plug in my measurement (or average of multiple of them) into y=wx, I get a good estimate of y?

Comment: @user1384636 for applying a model, you have to decide how "good" you want your estimate of `y` to be. If "n=10 measurements of the same object [gives] a pretty good estimate of y," then you have a basis for decision. Error of an estimate typically goes inversely with the square root of the number of observations. If your error in `y` with $n$  = 10 measurements is 1 unit, then $n$ = 5 will give an error of about 1.4 units, $n$ = 3 will give an error of about 1.8 units, and $n$ = 1 an error of about 3.2 units. Choose $n$ based on the cost of measurement and the cost of error in estimating `y`.